# PostgreSQL: Query user from table along with list of user roles

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join, select

I'm trying to query a user from my user table, while also getting a list of user roles from the user_role table. Here's my schema:

```
user
---------------------
|uuid    | username |
---------------------
|xxx-xx-x|     Joe  |
---------------------

user_role
----------------------
|user_uuid| role_uuid |
----------------------
|xxx-xx-x |  yyy-yy-y |
----------------------
|xxx-xx-x |  zzz-zz-z |
----------------------

role
----------------------
|role_uuid|      name |
----------------------
|yyy-yy-y | Moderator |
----------------------
|zzz-zz-z |    Tester |
----------------------
```

Here's my current query that only gets user info:

```
SELECT u.uuid, u.username FROM user AS u WHERE u.uuid = ($1)
```

How do I modify this to also get a list (array) of the roles a user has? I'd like to be able to do this in one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is aggregation in a lateral join:

```
SELECT u.uuid, u.username, r.role_names
FROM users AS u 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT array_agg(r.name) role_names
    FROM role r
    INNER JOIN user_role ur on ur.role_uuid = r.role_uuid
    WHERE ur.user_uuid = u.uuid
) r
WHERE u.uuid = $1
```

Notes:

- parentheses are not needed around the scalar parameter
- `user` is a SQL keyword, hence not a good choice for a table name - I renamed it to `users` in the query